# Serialized Data Displaying Letter by Letter Django

Tags: python, json, django, ajax

I'm learning to work with JSON and so I'm running a simple example to create a list item in my template for each object in my django model. My output looks like this:

[image]

So I wanted each `<li>` to show just the actual value in Name.  How can I amend my code to achieve that?

views.py

```
def Ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        exporter = serializers.serialize("json", Proforma.objects.all())
        print(exporter)
        data = json.dumps(exporter)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

```
$("#populate").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/more",
    success: function(data) {
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $('ul').append('<li>'+data[i]+'</li>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:

Here is the output from the console:

```
(index):739 [{"model": "Poseidon.proforma", "pk": 24, "fields": {"Name": "greg", "Shipment": 4, "Exporter": "greg", "QuoteNo": "jiojo", "Date": "ijoi", "Consignee": 10, "MethodOfDispatch": "ujhiuh", "TypeOfShipment": "iuhiu", "PortOfLoading": "huyg", "PortOfDischarge": "uioj", "Terms": "iugh", "ProductCode": "utyg", "DescriptionOfGoods": "iuhi", "UnitQty": "ug", "UnitType": "t", "Price": "iuh", "Amount": "iy", "BankDetails": "guyt", "AdditionalInfo": "gy", "InvoiceTotal": "tf", "Place": "uyg", "SignatoryCompanyBuyer": "uyf", "SignatoryCompany": "utfy", "NameSignerBuyer": "guyg", "NameSigner": "uy", "SignatureBuyer": "fy", "Signature": "trf", "CreatedBy": "uyg"}}]
```

Comment: try to log the data in ajax and attach to your question please

Comment: sorry not exactly sure what you mean by log the data - could you please clarify for me

Comment: `console.log(data);` in the ajax response to log to developer tools in chrome and edit your question with the result

Comment: ok added above - that's what I thought but was not sure. thank you.

Comment: you cant print whole object in a `<li>` tag, try to fix it please

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand - I can't fix it because I don't know how to fix it...that's my question if you're able to explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the ajax because you cant print a whole object in the `li` tag:

try this(would print "Poseidon.proforma" on the `li` tag):

```
$("#populate").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/more",
    success: function(data) {
      var data = JSON.parse(data); // parse the string response to JSON
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        $('ul').append('<li>'+data[i]["model"]+'</li>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

if you want a to understand the problem i think [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) may help

Comment: Ok I tried this, but now it is simply printing 'undefined' on a ton of ```li``` tags

Comment: sorry, you should parse the response from string to JSON, now it should work